# Convert time column in character format to manipulable time format in R

Tags: r, datetime, time, timestamp, lubridate

My question is about the standardization of column b. I need these data to be in a format that makes it easier to construct graphics.

```
a<- c("Jackson Brice / The Shocker","Flash Thompson", "Mr. Harrington","Mac Gargan","Betty Brant", "Ann Marie Hoag","Steve Rogers / Captain America", "Pepper Potts", "Karen") 
b<- c("2:30", "2:15", "2", "1:15", "1:15", "1", ":55",":45", "v")

ab <- cbind.data.frame(a,b)

                               a    b
1    Jackson Brice / The Shocker 2:30
2                 Flash Thompson 2:15
3                 Mr. Harrington    2
4                     Mac Gargan 1:15
5                    Betty Brant 1:15
6                 Ann Marie Hoag    1
7 Steve Rogers / Captain America    1
8                   Pepper Potts  :45
9                          Karen    v
```

as outuput:

```
                            a        b
1    Jackson Brice / The Shocker 00:02:30
2                 Flash Thompson 00:02:15
3                 Mr. Harrington 00:02:00
4                     Mac Gargan 00:01:15
5                    Betty Brant 00:01:15
6                 Ann Marie Hoag 00:01:00
7 Steve Rogers / Captain America 00:01:00
8                   Pepper Potts 00:00:45
9                          Karen 00:00:00
```

If possible, the objects of the column b in the manipulable format of time.

Comment: `Steve Rogers / Captain America    1` row doesn't seem correct. The value is actually `:55` in vector `b` defined by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've had to make a few assumptions about what you are trying to do, e.g. units and what you want done with character values but hopefully this function will give you something to work with.

The big challenge with time is that you need some fairly clear rules when parsing it from text.  As I results I have had to put a number of `if` statements in the function to make it work but wherever possible, try and keep your time formats as consistent as possible.

```
library(lubridate)

formatTime <- function(x) {

    # Check for a : seperator in the text
    if(grepl(":",x, fixed = TRUE)) {

        y <- unlist(strsplit(x,":", fixed = TRUE))

        # If there is no value before the : then add "00" before the :
        if(y[1]=="") {
            z <- ms(paste("00",y[2],collapse = ":"), quiet=TRUE)
        } else {
            z <- ms(paste(y,collapse = ":"), quiet=TRUE)
        }
    } else { 

        # If there is no : then add "00" after the :
        z <- ms(paste(x,"00",collapse = ":"), quiet=TRUE)
    }

    # If it did not pare with ms, i.e. it was a character, then assign zero time "00:00"
    if(is.na(z)) z <- ms("0:00")

    # Converted to duration due to issues returning period with lapply.  
    # Make dataframe to retun units and name with lapply.
    return(data.frame(time = as.duration(z)))
}

# Convert factor variable to character
ab$b <- as.character(ab$b)

ab <- cbind(ab,rbindlist(lapply(ab$b,formatTime)))
```

I started by trying to work with a time period but it wouldn't return correctly with the apply statement so I converted to a duration.  This may not display the same as your example but it should play nice with graphs.
Let me know if I've missed what you needed and I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `tidyr::separate` and `tidyr::unite` can be achieved. The approach is to first replace a value containing `alphabetic` with `00:00:00`. Separate parts in 3 columns. Using `dplyr::mutate_at` all the 3 columns is changed to `00` format. Finally, unite all the three columns.

```
library(tidyverse)

ab %>% mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%  #Change any factor in character
  mutate(b = ifelse(grepl("[[:alpha:]]", b), "00:00:00", b)) %>%
  mutate(b = ifelse(grepl(":", b), b, paste(b,"00",sep=":")) ) %>%
  separate(b, into = c("b1", "b2", "b3"), sep = ":", fill="left", extra = "drop") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("b")), 
      funs(sprintf("%02d", as.numeric(ifelse(is.na(.) | . == "",0,.))))) %>%
  unite("b", starts_with("b"), sep=":")

#                                a        b
# 1    Jackson Brice / The Shocker 00:02:30
# 2                 Flash Thompson 00:02:15
# 3                 Mr. Harrington 00:02:00
# 4                     Mac Gargan 00:01:15
# 5                    Betty Brant 00:01:15
# 6                 Ann Marie Hoag 00:01:00
# 7 Steve Rogers / Captain America 00:00:55
# 8                   Pepper Potts 00:00:45
# 9                          Karen 00:00:00
```

**Data:**

```
a<- c("Jackson Brice / The Shocker","Flash Thompson", "Mr. Harrington","Mac Gargan","Betty Brant",
 "Ann Marie Hoag","Steve Rogers / Captain America", "Pepper Potts", "Karen") 
b<- c("2:30", "2:15", "2", "1:15", "1:15", "1", ":55",":45", "v")

ab <- cbind.data.frame(a,b
```